# Change color of specific word

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe

I have a text that I'm getting from a json and I want to change the color of some words that appears on the text like `recusada` for example. I created a pipe to try to do it:

```
 transform(valor:any):any{
    console.log("texto", valor);
    return valor.replace(/recusada/, '<span style="color: red">$&</span>');
 }
```

This is the html:

```
   <p *ngFor="let historico of disputa.historico"> {{historico.texto | filtroHistorico: historico.texto}} </p>
```

The only problem is that instead of just change the color of `recusada`to red the text looks like this:

> Proposta no valor de R$:5762 `<span style="color: red">recusada</span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `innerHTML` in order to render *html*.

So your code should look like this

```
<p *ngFor="let historico of disputa.historico" [innerHTML]="historico.texto | filtroHistorico: historico.texto"> </p>
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MB9mwpWXFyQurlmE81W8?p=preview)

Comment: Wow, didn't now there's such a property like `innerHtml`, thank you very much man :)